# Apache mod_proxy port redirect for game server?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I've got a game running on port xxxx (server, that is). I made a rule for mod proxy in Apache to forward that port to 25555 /game (which theoretically should work. Problem comes when conencting, since I'm led to believe that the Headers are incorrect or basically Apache mod proxy only works with http or ftp traffic. It doesn't forward all packets directly to the destination and back with proxy reverse? For websites on other ports it works, just not anything non-http or ftp.

Example config:

(only summarizing)

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /folder/ http://localhost:8180/folder

ProxyPassReverse /folder/ http://localhost:8180/folder

Answer (score 1):

Yep, proxying is for specific types of traffic. HTTP, FTP, AJP, etc. By its nature a proxy server needs to know the nature of the traffic its dealing with. Proxy/Apache is not the correct tool to use for port forwarding of any connections/traffic. You need some other lower level network utility for generic forwarning.

If you're on linux I think you can use iptables or something for this. Maybe go and ask on Server Fault, as generic forwarding is more suited over there.